# Help writing a Ruby on Rails search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Note object, which has a `start_date` field (date, required) and an `end_date` field (date, optional).

How can I write a search (in Ruby 1.9.2 & Rails 3) that will find notes that meet these 2 conditions:

1. `end_date` field isn't empty
2. parameter `input_date` is in the period between (`start_date` + 1 day) and `end_date`

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the problem. I mean, do you get an error or you simply forgot to read the [ActiveRecord documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)? ;)

You can use the `#where` method to create the query.

Answer (score 0):

You might also like this: https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic :)